# Flag obsolete question for closing

Tags: support, questions, flagging, off-topic

Yesterday, I posted https://superuser.com/questions/836446/why-is-flash-player-trying-to-load-flex-framework-rsls-swz-files-from-my-serve/836750#836750, and today I found that the problem was due to a temporary error on Adobe's server.

On Stackoverflow, there's a flag to close "Off topic" because:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced
>   or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be
>   on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help
>   future readers.

I went to flag my question similarly here, but I didn't see a "one-time problem" flag similar to the SO one.

Should I flag my question for closing, and if so, what flag should I use?

Comment: Just flag it for moderator review.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply choose *Other…* and just type in what you'd like us to do.

We don't have such a close reason because it'd be used very rarely.

Answer (score 1):

As OP, you can delete your own question if you feel it doesn't add anything of value to the community, no need to go through the full review/close process.